# How to call a method on a dependency with SpEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-el

I want to call a method on a dependency in my controller in `@PreAuthorize` annotation using SpEL, but I cannot figure it out, I tried a bunch of things but cannot get it to work.

The method looks something like this (SpEL is wrong here):

```
@Override
@GetMapping("/count")
@PreAuthorize("@puppetSecurity.isPuppetCountAllowed(puppetMapper.toEntity(#puppetType))")
public ResponseEntity<PuppetCountDto> getPupetCount(PuppetType puppetType) {
    // CODE
}
```

I want to call the puppetMapper dependency's method toEntity and convert the parameter of the endpoint method. How would I do that?

Comment: Use `@puppetMapper` (which will reference the bean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I wanted to reference a **MapStruct** mapper, which was registered as a bean, with the name of the interface instead of the actual bean name which is the implementation.

I had a mapper interface called **PuppetMapper**, registered as a Spring bean, but
looking at the actual implementation, the name I had to reference was **PuppetMapperImpl**.

So the PreAuthorize SpEL would look like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("@puppetSecurity.isPuppetCountAllowed(@puppetMapperImpl.toEntity(#puppetType))")
```